# handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession never get called : ios7 Background Transfer Service

Tags: ios7, service, background, download

I spent 2 days now, and I think that I need some help.
Of course I tried to search in stackOverflow but did not get anythng to solve my issue.

My app is downloading files (2MB up to 100MB).

I am using the Background transfer service (ios7)

when the user click on a button I launch the download as below (immediatly he presses home button):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration * backgroundConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:self.url];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: backgroundConfig delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
self.downloadTask =[ self.session downloadTaskWithURL:url];
[self.downloadTask resume];
```

I Have the delegate methode working well :

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

I have also set :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"<<<<<<<<<  Save completionHandler >>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

    self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
}


-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
{
    NSLog(@"Background URL session %@ finished events.\n", session);

    AppDelegate * delegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(delegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler)
    {
        void (^handler)() = delegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler;
        handler();
    }

}
```

in the AppDelegate.h

I get my block property :

```
@property (copy) void (^backgroundSessionCompletionHandler)();
```

Actually I followed this tuto : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595

My problem is that sometimes I get my file downloaded and sometimes no. only a part of the file is present in the filesystem.

BUT I never get handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession called, never !

Can anyone help regarding this issue ?

thanks in advance

Comment: how did you try to detect if it gets called? handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession gets called only when the transfers finish while your app has been killed by the system... you can't just set a breakpoint in there and expect to hit it. To properly see if it gets called you should log some messages and look for them. I don't know how you could get you app terminated in this way in the simulator. I am also looking into this and will return with news if I find any